# How do I Retry an observable returned via a SelectMany call from another observable

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I want to retry an observable when an error occurs.  In the two cases below, I only see the Retry work in case 1.  However, in case 2, the Retry does not happen.

What is the difference between these two cases?  Is it because the Retry in case 2 would just Retry if `subject` error'ed?  If that is the case, then wouldn't the `Subscribe` in case 2 only be acting on `subject`, in which case I don't understand when `ErrorProducer` is actually subscribed to.

In case 2 my understanding was that `SelectMany(_ => ErrorProducer(3))` returns an `IObservable<int>` and then the Retry and Subscribe calls act on that.  Though it seems I need to add Retry directly to the `ErrorProducer` call as in case 1.

```
        public ViewModel()
        {
            var subject = new Subject<int>();

            //Case 1: comment out case 2 when running case 1
            subject
              .SelectMany(_ => ErrorProducer(3).Retry())
              .Subscribe();

            subject.OnNext(1);


            //Case 2: comment out case 1 when running case 2
            //subject
            //    .SelectMany(_ => ErrorProducer(3))
            //    .Retry()
            //    .Subscribe();

            //subject.OnNext(1);
        }

        private IObservable<int> ErrorProducer(int i)
        {
            int count = 0;
            return Observable.Create<int>(observer =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Doing work");

                if (count++ < i)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Failed");
                    observer.OnError(new Exception());
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Done");
                    observer.OnNext(count);
                    observer.OnCompleted();
                }
                return Disposable.Empty;
            });
        }
```

**Output:**

```
Case 1:
    Doing work
    Failed
    Doing work
    Failed
    Doing work
    Failed
    Doing work
    Done


Case 2:
    Doing work
    Failed
```

Comment: @Progman Hey, I just double checked.  The cases were meant to be run one at a time.  I updated the question to specify that.  But when running just case 1 I see the output get to "Done", while running just case 2 stops at a single "Failed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case 1 the `.Retry()` retries the observable returned by the `ErrorProducer` method.

In case 2 the `.Retry()` retries the `SelectMany` which only produces a value when the `subject` produces a value.

`Retry` simply ignores errors and resubscribes to the observable that it's attached to. The behaviour depends on the observable it's attached to.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  One thing that I am still a bit unclear on.  In either case, the call to Subscribe() is subscribing to the subject right (similar to Retry in case 2) ?  So whenever subject produces a value, the SelectMany call to ErrorProducer is triggered.  When exactly is the observable returned by ErrorProducer subscribed to?  Does SelectMany do it somehow?  How come we don't need to have ErrorProducer.Subscribe() in the SelectMany, similar to ErrorProducer.Retry in case 1?

Comment: @Flack - For each value produced by the subject, the `SelectMany` subscribes to it's inner observable and returns all of the values that each inner observable produces. `SelectMany` ignores completes from the inner observable and only completes when the subject completes. Any error, however, from the inner observable, causes the `SelectMany` to error and then stop.